# Integrate camera in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app which uses camera.
I have been looking at BTLFullScreenCameraController for this purpose but I am not sure if this is the best choise?

I will be needing the flip function for back and front camera, and flash ability to. 
I like the way camera options are structured on the iphone4, and would like to do something similar in my app.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Regards, tomas

Answer (score 0):

If you like iPhone's default camera, why not just use the default view?

```
UIImagePickerController *camera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentModalViewController:camera animated:YES];
[camera release];
```